# Cómo crear slide de imágenes con ViewPager y Glide en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo un slide de imágenes usando un `ViewPager` que previamente se cargan la imágenes y son enviadas al `ViewPager`, Tengo lo siguiente:

layout donde se muestra el viewpager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_photogallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp" />
```

CustomPagerAdapter.java

```
class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "ImageViewPage";
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    private int[] mResourceIds;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] resourceIds) {
        mContext = context;
        mResourceIds = resourceIds;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResourceIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "instantiateItem() called with: " + "container = [" + container + "], position = [" + position + "]");
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
        imageView.setImageResource(mResourceIds[position]);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        Log.d(TAG, "destroyItem() called with: " + "container = [" + container + "], position = [" + position + "], object = [" + object + "]");
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

pager_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/about_alt_icon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Cargo el slide de imágenes de esa forma

```
    int[] resourceIds = new int[]{
            R.drawable.no_content
    };

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_photogallery);

    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this, resourceIds));
    }
```

Lo que intento ahora es que las imágenes no sean recursos internos de  la app, sino que se carguen des de una url, usando la [librería Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), la fuente de las imágenes quiero que sea un `array de strings` y dentro del `ViewPager` se descarguen las imágenes y visualización en el `ImageView`, en caso de que el array este vacio cargue el recurso interno drawable/no_content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenos días, aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
    String[] myUrls;

       @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "instantiateItem() called with: " + "container = [" + container + "], position = [" + position + "]");
            View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

            Glide
            .with(mContext)
            .load(myUrls[position])
            .error(R.drawable.no_content)
            .into(imageView);

            container.addView(itemView);

            return itemView;
```

Yo no he usado Glide pero en el caso de Picasso si una Url viene vacía te va a dar error, rellena la String con algo por ejemplo "noUrl":

```
.load(!myUrls[position].trim().isEmpty() ? myUrls[position] : "noUrl")
```

Entonces intentará cargar la url y al no encontrarla cargará la imagen que se encuentre en `.error(R.drawable.no_content)`

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

**Solucionado!**

Modificando un poco el código que ya tenia para crear un slide de imágenes

```
class PhotoGalleryPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "ImageViewPage";
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    private String[] mResources;

    public PhotoGalleryPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] resources) {
        mContext = context;
        mResources = resources;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "instantiateItem() called with: " + "container = [" + container + "], position = [" + position + "]");
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

        Log.d(TAG, "load in gallery:" + mResources[position] + "#end");
        final ImageView iv_photo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

        if (!mResources[position].equals("")){
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(mResources[position].trim())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
                    .error(R.drawable.error_image)
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(iv_photo);
        }
        //iv_photo.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        Log.d(TAG, "destroyItem() called with: " + "container = [" + container + "], position = [" + position + "], object = [" + object + "]");
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

}
```

en el page_item.xml establecer la imagen para mostrar el estado de vacio `empty-state`.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/about_alt_icon"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/no_content" />
```

Su uso

```
String[] resourcePhotos = myItem.getPhotoGallery().split(",");

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_photogallery);

if (viewPager != null) {
    viewPager.setAdapter(new PhotoGalleryPagerAdapter(this, resourcePhotos));
}
```